# Not work world partition UE5. How fix that?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

World Partition is not working for me. I create a level then convert it to world partition. Then I get the following error:

```
Conversion completed:
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:161][ 0]LogD3D12RHI: Display: Not using pipeline state disk cache per r.D3D12.PSO.DiskCache=0
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:161][ 0]LogD3D12RHI: Display: Not using driver-optimized pipeline state disk cache per r.D3D12.PSO.DriverOptimizedDiskCache=0
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:348][ 0]LogTextureFormatETC2: Display: ETC2 Texture loading DLL: TextureConverter.dll
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:356][ 0]LogTextureFormatOodle: Display: Oodle Texture TFO init; latest sdk version=2.9.5
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:356][ 0]LogTextureFormatOodle: Display: Oodle Texture loading DLL: oo2tex_win64_2.9.5.dll
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:369][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Android'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:370][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Android_ASTC'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:370][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Android_DXT'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:370][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Android_ETC2'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:370][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'AndroidClient'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:370][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Android_ASTCClient'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:370][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Android_DXTClient'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:370][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Android_ETC2Client'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:370][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Android_Multi'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:370][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Android_MultiClient'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:373][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'HoloLens'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:373][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'HoloLensClient'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:377][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'IOS'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:378][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'IOSClient'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:381][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Linux'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:381][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'LinuxEditor'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:381][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'LinuxServer'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:381][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'LinuxClient'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:385][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'LinuxArm64'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:385][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'LinuxArm64Server'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:385][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'LinuxArm64Client'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:388][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'TVOS'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:388][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'TVOSClient'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:394][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'Windows'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:394][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'WindowsEditor'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:394][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'WindowsServer'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:394][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Loaded TargetPlatform 'WindowsClient'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:394][ 0]LogTargetPlatformManager: Display: Building Assets For WindowsEditor
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:403][ 0]LogAudioDebug: Display: Lib vorbis DLL was dynamically loaded.
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:470][ 0]LogShaderCompilers: Display: Compiling shader autogen file: ../../../../../../Users/adm/Documents/Unreal Projects/ MyProject4/Intermediate/ShaderAutogen/PCD3D_SM5/AutogenShaderHeaders.ush
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:470][ 0]LogShaderCompilers: Display: Autogen file is unchanged, skipping write.
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:470][ 0]LogShaderCompilers: Display: Compiling shader autogen file: ../../../../../../Users/adm/Documents/Unreal Projects/ MyProject4/Intermediate/ShaderAutogen/PCD3D_ES31/AutogenShaderHeaders.ush
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:470][ 0]LogShaderCompilers: Display: Autogen file is unchanged, skipping write.
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:496][ 0]LogDerivedDataCache: Display: ../../../Engine/DerivedDataCache/Compressed.ddp: Opened pak cache for reading. (1096 MiB)
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:515][ 0]LogDerivedDataCache: Display: Performance to C:/Users/adm/AppData/Local/UnrealEngine/Common/DerivedDataCache: Latency=0.05ms. RandomReadSpeed=490.03MBs, RandomWriteSpeed=57.53MBs. Assigned SpeedClass 'Local'
[2022.06.26-14.00.57:524][ 0]LogShaderCompilers: Display: Using Local Shader Compiler with 5 workers.
[2022.06.26-14.00.59:317][ 0]LogEditorDomain: Display: EditorDomain is Disabled
[2022.06.26-14.00.59:531][ 0]LogTexture: Display: Texture Encode Speed: Final (cook).
[2022.06.26-14.00.59
```

after that, no matter how I set up the loading distance and the size of the cells, my objects like still remain visible for kilometers even if I set the distance to 300. Please help

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for programming questions, so we need to see your code to help you debug your problem.  As explained in [ask],  *if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program! Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*  For help with this, see [mcve].  For tips on writing questions that are most likely to get answers, see https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: its problem not with code. This is a problem either with unrial or with my ability to use its functions

Comment: I would try just using the default open world template UE5 comes with

Answer (score 0):

Please check these things:
1.Is Spatially Loaded shall be checked for actors in actor detail pannel so that can be loaded and unloaded automatically by world partition system.
2.Cells load and unload will be activated by streaming source which is default enabled for player controller or you can use World Partition Streaming component for activating.
Document:https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/world-partition-in-unreal-engine/